# How to specify the i-th axis of array in julia

Tags: julia

How can I simplify the code using `for` loop?

`eta` and `T` are 6-order tensor arrays and `size(eta) == size(T)` .

```
using  InvertedIndices
one_to_N = [1:6;]
eta[:,1,1,1,1,1] = vec(sum(T, dims=one_to_N[Not(1)]))
eta[1,:,1,1,1,1] = vec(sum(T, dims=one_to_N[Not(2)]))
eta[1,1,:,1,1,1] = vec(sum(T, dims=one_to_N[Not(3)]))
eta[1,1,1,:,1,1] = vec(sum(T, dims=one_to_N[Not(4)]))
eta[1,1,1,1,:,1] = vec(sum(T, dims=one_to_N[Not(5)]))
eta[1,1,1,1,1,:] = vec(sum(T, dims=one_to_N[Not(6)]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. Here are some that quickly come to mind:

You can do it like this:

```
for i in 1:6
    eta[ifelse.(1:6 .== i, :, 1)...] = vec(sum(T, dims=one_to_N[Not(i)]))
end
```

or like this:

```
for i in 1:6
    eta[ntuple(j -> j == i ? (:) : 1, 6)...] = vec(sum(T, dims=one_to_N[Not(i)]))
end
```

or like this:

```
for i in 1:6
    eta[(j == i ? (:) : 1 for j in 1:6)...] = vec(sum(T, dims=one_to_N[Not(i)]))
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating the sums and then copying them into `eta`, you can also just write directly using `sum!`. Making views with index `1:1` rather than `1` means that these dimensions are not dropped, and hence `sum!` can deduce which dimensions to sum over:

```
data = rand(Int8, 4,7,2);  # originally T, with ndims(T)==6, reduced for clarity
eta = ones(4,7,2);

for dim in 1:ndims(data)
    ind = ntuple(d -> d==dim ? (:) : (1:1), ndims(data))
    sum!(view(eta, ind...), data)
end
```

This gives:

```
julia> eta
4×7×2 Array{Float64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
   -1.0  -29.0  -581.0  118.0  -106.0  189.0  198.0
 -100.0    1.0     1.0    1.0     1.0    1.0    1.0
  468.0    1.0     1.0    1.0     1.0    1.0    1.0
 -214.0    1.0     1.0    1.0     1.0    1.0    1.0

[:, :, 2] =
 -130.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0

julia> dim = 2;

julia> ind = ntuple(d -> d==dim ? (:) : (1:1), ndims(data))
(1:1, Colon(), 1:1)

julia> view(eta, ind...)
1×7×1 view(::Array{Float64, 3}, 1:1, :, 1:1) with eltype Float64:
[:, :, 1] =
 -1.0  -29.0  -581.0  118.0  -106.0  189.0  198.0

julia> sum(data, dims=(1,3))
1×7×1 Array{Int64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 80  -29  -581  118  -106  189  198
```

Notice that `eta[1]` is overwritten several times here, so the result depends on the order of the operations, not just on the `data` array.